# Trying to move html element to a specific location within a table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to move an HTML element to a specific location within a table. For example, I have a disabled button labeled "abcd" and a table with cell value of "xyz". I want to move the button "abcd" on top of the cell with the value "xyz" by referencing that value.

So far, the code I have for the javascript function looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveObject() {
        var label = prompt("Please enter object to move", "");
        var location = prompt("Please enter cell location", "");
        var element = document.getElementById(label);
    }
</script>
```

How do I reference the cell value so that I can tell the object to move there?

Comment: Also, put all new information in your question, not down here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option using `document.getElementsByTagName` and `prepend` to add button to cell value

1. Get all tds using `document.getElementsByTagName('TD')`
2. Loop all td elements using for of
3. Look for cell with text xyz and prepend disabled button- abcd

```js
function moveObject() {
        let tds = document.getElementsByTagName('TD')
    let btn = document.getElementById('abcd')
        for(let cell of tds){
      if(cell.innerHTML ==='xyz'){
        cell.prepend(btn)
      }
    }
        }
```

```css
table tr td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button  id="abcd" disabled>abcd</button>
<button onclick="moveObject()">Move</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to replicate this without using innerHTML?

Comment: You can use cell.textContent instead of cell.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following structure for a html table:

```
 <table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell C</td>
    <td>Cell D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see every cell is a `<td>` element.

Since our table has an unique id - myTable - we can get all it's TD elements by calling:

```
var cells=document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td");
```

The variable **cells** holds a html collection of all the TD elements of **myTable** but what we are really interested in is the actual content of a cell - so we need to loop over this array and refer to each cells content using **.firstChild.data**. 
If we compare this to a string we can see which cell matches.

Here's an example:

```js
function getCell(myString) {
  var cells = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var a = 0; a < cells.length; a++) {
    if (cells[a].firstChild.data == myString) {
      return cells[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
console.log(getCell("Cell C"));
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell C</td>
    <td>Cell D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`prompt()` is a crappy interface. Do this instead:

- Wrap everything in a block level element (`div`, `section`, `main`, etc), we'll refer to it as the *"parent"*
- Register the parent to the click event either by on-event property:

  ```
  parent.onclick = callback
  ```

  or by Event Listener:

  ```
  parent.addEventListener('click', callback)
  ```

  now the parent will detect all clicks on anything within the parent.
- Use `event.target` to determine what was clicked. No id, class, or tagName is needed to identify `event.target`, but use `.matches()` to narrow down `event.target` in if/else control.

```js
function addButton(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  const buttons = this.querySelectorAll('button');
  const prompt = this.querySelector('legend');

  if (clicked.matches('button')) {
    if (clicked.matches('.selected')) {
      clicked.classList.remove('selected');
      prompt.textContent = 'Click a Button';
      prompt.style.color = 'black';
    } else {
      for (let button of buttons) {
        button.classList.remove('selected');
      }
      clicked.classList.add('selected');
      prompt.textContent = 'Click a Cell';
      prompt.style.color = 'red';
    }
  } else if (clicked.matches('td')) {
    let button = this.querySelector('.selected');
    if (button) {
      clicked.appendChild(button);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

document.querySelector('main').onclick = addButton;
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1px
}

th::before,
td::before {
  content: '\a0';
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.75rem
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Click a Button</legend>
    <button>X</button>
    <button>X</button>
    <button>X</button>
    <button>X</button>
  </fieldset>
</main>
```